# how to wildcard attach multiple files to an artifact in maven?

Tags: maven

In my maven project, the ant plugin generate multiple war files and I want to attach them all in the same artifact. I tried the build-helper-maven-plugin like this

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.7</version>
 <executions>
 <execution>
 <id>attach-artifacts</id>
 <phase>package</phase>
 <goals>
  <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
 </goals>
 <configuration>
 <artifacts>
<artifact>
  <file>${project.build.directory}/*.war</file>
  <type>war</type>
</artifact>                 
</artifacts>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I don't want to specify each war file separately because the ant plugin is dynamic. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Providing wildcards for single artifacts does not seem to be supported by the Build Helper plugin (btw, if it did, it would likely use the includes/excludes configuration [used by Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)).

I've learned that, if you choose to use Maven, it's best to just adjust your build to "the Maven way."

In this case, you should revise your build to not use the ant war plugin, and instead have a multi-module build with a separate module (sub-project) for each war file.

Alternatively, in the past I have accomplished something like you are doing via the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies.html), where the wars are all shipped together in a single tar/gz file. The archive (which contains each of the wars) is then attached to the build.

Note that you should prefer to have your "web apps" module have a artifact type of "pom." The assembly plugin will attach the archives to the final build.

For more information, I've found that Sonatype's online books are a great resource:
http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books

Comment: I have checked the code of build-helper-maven-plugin and it doesn't support for wildcards. It is an interesting idea to pack all the war into a jar but it add an extra step for my deployment process.

Comment: You wouldn't pack the wars into a jar, you would pack them into a tar/gz file. Your extra step would then consist of `tar xvzf` - I still think the multi-module build approach is the way to go.